# How to select multiple class selector with jquery like selector pattern

Tags: javascript, function, constructor

I'm trying to create a id(#) and an class(.) css selector. eg. [pluginName(selector)] similar to jQuery in my tiny plugin. The getElementById works well but the getElementByClassName is not working with the for loop to select multiple selector on the page. Here is what i got so far.

```
  function $(selector){
    if(typeof string !== 'string' || !selector){
      return false;
    }
    if(selector){
      if(window === this){
        return new $(selector);
      }
      var selectorType = 'querySelectorAll';
      if(selector.indexOf('#') === 0){
        selectorType = 'getElementById';
        selector = selector.substr(1,selector.length);
        this.el = document[selectorType](selector);
        return this;
      } else if(selector.indexOf('.') === 0){
        selectorType = 'getElementsByClassName';
        selector = selector.substr(1,selector.length);
       this.el = document[selectorType](selector);
       var i = 0;
       for(i = 0; i < this.el.length; i++){
       this.el[i];
       }
       return this;
    }
  }
```

I ended up with something like this.

```
$.prototype = {
hide: function(){
  this.el.style.display = 'none';
  return this;
};
```

Then:

```
var btns = document.querySelector('.btn');
btns.addEventListener('click', myshow);
function myshow(){
  $('.showoff').hide();
}
```

HTML:

```
<button class="btn">Try it</button> <br>
<p id="showoff">ELEMENT</p> <br>
<p class="showoff">ELEMENT</p>
```

Now the question is how do i loop through the class(.) selector so i can select multiple class(.) selector on a page with the code provided.

Comment: why not just use the [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) itself?

Comment: also, what exactly do you want to achieve? `this.el[i]` is a useless statement and `return` inside a `for` loop will return from the function immediately, breaking from the for loop... but there is no function in your code.

Comment: Check out the full code

Answer (score 0):

```
function select(selector) {
   var selectors = selector.split(',')
   for(i=0;i<selectors.length;i++) {  
       /// code
   }
}

select('#id,.class1,.class2')
```

Comment: what about `.class1.class2`, `.class1 .class2` and dozens other possible selectors? also how does this help with the non-working `for` loop from the question?

Answer (score 0):

I will take a wild guess that you would like to make the `.hide()` method work on all elements which have the class.

Looks like you already realize that the `getElementsByClassName` returns a NodeList (not a single element, but an iterable collection), however there is no point iterating directly in the `$()` constructor.

You need to iterate inside the `hide` method:

**edit**: add example of chaining methods

```js
'use strict';
function $(selector) {
  if(!this){
    return new $(selector);
  }
  this.el = document.querySelectorAll(selector)
  return this
}

$.prototype = {
  hide: function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.el.length; i++) {
      this.el[i].style.display = 'none'
    }
    return this
  },
  click: function(callback) {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.el.length; i++) {
      this.el[i].onclick = callback
    }
    return this
  },
  showBlockLater: function(ms) {
    var el = this.el
    setTimeout(function() {
      for (var i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
        el[i].style.display = 'block'
      }
    }, ms)
    return this
  }
}


$('.btn').click(myshow)
var showoff = $('.showoff')
function myshow() {
  showoff.hide().showBlockLater(1000)
}
```

```html
<button class="btn">Try it</button>
<p class="showoff">ELEMENT</p>
<p class="showoff">ELEMENT</p>
```

Comment: I was wondering if i could use this in a production level. What's your opinion?

Comment: perfectly fine for a personal project, though if multiple people will need to maintain it, then it would be OK only if you provide very few helper functions and not create a whole framework of your own - otherwise you might be better off with actual jQuery, or even learning React or Vue or some other modern framework that other people also want to learn..

Comment: Hmmm good thought. I'm using jQuery in my project. But i have read articles trying to know about the disadvantages of using the jQuery library. 1, file size if self hosting on my server. 2, version upgrading might cause problem. Since a lot of articles recommend using the google cdn, google is restricted in some country. I'm not trying to re-write a full library as jQuery but I'm trying to be specific with the methods i need only in the project since I'm using vanilla javascript.

Comment: I would like to know how i can implement a chaining pattern like jQuery does in this plugin. I ended up with somthing like this;

Comment: I added an example how to chain methods, returning `this` is sufficient... though you shouldn't care about file size of jQuery more than about creating working code

Comment: Oh sorry for that. I stupidly edited the perfect solution to my questions.

Comment: In your opinion are you saying that i should instead use jQuery? and if yes, would it be best to self host it on my server and not caring about the file size?. Or am i wasting time trying to do something that has been done already? and aslo from your perspective does this method look rich enough?. I'm totally confuse but not convinced. Please tell me what's your perfect suggestion about this.

Comment: https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js is 35KB gzipped, 85KB raw, if you put your `<script>` tags at the end of `<body>` so that your HTML and CSS will load first, then it doesn't matter whether you use CDN or hosting your own copy IMHO... other people have strong opinions either way, because there are so many factors that influence micro-performance and every project has to decide themselves